# How to use a shared key and certificate for all users with OpenVPN?

Tags: linux, security, vpn, openvpn, certificate

I have an OpenVPN server which authenticates to an Active Directory and asks therefore each user for a username and passphrase.

On top of that it also requires each user to have a client certificate and client key (+ server ca.crt).

**Question**

I would like that each user must login with their AD username and passphrase and that all clients shares the same client certificate and client key.

The reason I want a shared client certificate and key is for ease of management and it protects the network from someone brute forcing a password.

One way would be to just create one client like so

```
cd /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/
. /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/build-key client1
```

and give this to each user.

Is that the correct way under these conditions? Or should the client certificate and key be created in a special way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't do that, because once your single key is compromised for any reason (stolen laptop, trojan, employee leaving the company, etc.), you will need to give each user a new one, most likely resulting in more time spent than you saved initially by creating only one.

If you want to avoid the complexities of creating a CA and signing (and revoking) client certificates (although with the easy-rsa script it really isn't that hard), OpenVPN also supports static keys (generated with `openvpn --genkey`) that are very straightforward to handle (although they will also be used for encryption, instead of TLS).

Comment: +1 for this.  Note also that the client key is an important part of the security of the link.  I suspect that if all clients have the same private key, then given the complete ciphertext of one client's session, any other client can decrypt it.

Comment: @MadHatter : Only is symmetric key are used I assume?

Comment: Sorry, what?  The private key and certificate form an asymmetric keypair, the latter being signed by some other entity (hence, certificate).  Usually, these are used to negotiate a "nonce" session key, which is a symmetric key, yes.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: @MadHatter : Sorry about the nonsense I wrote =) But yes, that was what I meant to say =)

Answer (score 8):

First off, I agree with Ingmar Hupp, you don't want to be passing around one single key for a bunch of users.  It's really not part of a good security strategy.  Additionally, as he mentions, setting up a CA and signing/revoking keys using easy-rsa is quite easy, and IMO worth the additional "manpower" (if you will) to setup / maintain keys properly, instead of passing a single one around.

But anyway, the "technical" answer is to add

> duplicate-cn

to your server.conf file.

Comment: And you probably want `username-as-common-name` as well.

Comment: @ysdx Thank you for this option. Status in openvpn management console now shows real usernames instead of cert name